# How to list unpartitioned and unmounted disks in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, grep

I have a new Ubuntu machine. I can list the `nvme` disks using `lsblk` and `grep`:

```
lsblk -e7
```

[image]

```
lsblk -l | grep nvme
```

[image]

now I need to get just the unmounted and unpartitioned ones which are `nvme1n1` and `nvme2n1`. How can I achive that in this case?

Comment: Do nvme1 & 2 have partitions? I would expect lsblk to show them? And 8
GB is not particularly large for / (root). I typically allocate 30GB and currently use about 13GB with aggressive housecleaning and all data normally in /home on HDD.

Comment: Use `fdisk -l`. That will show all disks and their partitions if they exist whether they are mounted or not.

Comment: The mounted : mount|grep nvm|sed "s/.*\(nvme...\).*/\1/"|sort -u

Comment: sorry the grep not needed mount|sed -n  "s/.*\(nvme...\).*/\1/p"|sort -u

Comment: have a partition: lsblk -l |sed -n  "s/.*\(nvme...\)p.*/\1/p"|sort -u

Comment: have a partition and mounted: cat <(lsblk -l |sed -n  "s/.*\(nvme...\)p.*/\1/p") <(mount|sed -n "s/.*\(nvme...\).*/\1/p")|sort -u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
diff <(cat <(lsblk -l |sed -n  "s/.*\(nvme...\)p.*/\1/p") <(mount|sed -n "s/.*\(nvme...\).*/\1/p")|sort -u) <(lsblk -l |sed -n  "s/.*\(nvme...\).*/\1/p" |sort -u)
```

First : have a partition and mounted
Second : all from lsblk
And diff